# How can I use "IF" statement to determine the amount of free disk space to add to a VMDK?

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

The script I am using is below. We are upgrading our 1500 VDI's from Windows 10 1809 to 1909 and we want to automate the process as much as possible since this will be a process that we will have to do regularly with each new version Windows puts out. We are using SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager). The script works perfect for extending disk space for multiple machines. The .csv file it is importing only contains a list of virtual machines the script is to expand disk space on. I want to use an "if" statement to determine if the amount of free space is below 30GB and, if so, to add the needed disk space to bring it up to 30GB free space. Example: "if" free disk space is -lt 30GB, Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB (the difference to make 30GB free space available), "if" free space is -eq to 30GB, do nothing. I have researched Google and this site for anything remotely similar and wasn't able to find what I need. All help accomplishing this is appreciated.

```
##Task Change Disk Size
##Variable clear
$csvobjects = @()
$cskobject = @()
$network = @()
$isalive = @()

##Import VM name(s)
$csvobjects = Import-CSV -path "C:\Temp\ExpandHDDiskList.csv"

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false

connect-viserver -server anyserver.com -User anyuser@anyserver.com

foreach ($csvobject in $csvobjects){
##Variable clear
$network = @()
$isalive = @()
##Pre-change data gathering
$beforechange = (GET-VM -Name $csvobject.vmname | FT -auto CapacityGB|out-string)
##Stop VM
GET-VM -Name $csvobject.vmname | Get-HardDisk -Name 'Hard disk 1' | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB 75 -Confirm:$false
start-sleep -s 60

# Variable specifying the drive you want to extend
$drive_letter = "C"

# Script to get the partition sizes and then resize the volume
$size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Get-VMGuest` to get the free space within the guest VM.

Set the target amount of free space in a variable.  30GB (GB = 1024^3)

```
$gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
$space = 30 * $gb
```

Get the free space from the VM using `Get-VMGuest`

```
$vm = Get-VMGuest $csvobject.vmname
```

Now, assuming a single hard disk in the machine, determine if the free space is less than 30GB.  If it is, increase the hard disk size so that there is 30GB of free space.  The calculation takes the capacity of the disk and adds on the required free space (30GB) and then subtracts the current free space.  This is all done in bytes so convert it into GB and round it to a whole number to avoid weird disk sizes:

```
if ($vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace -lt $space) {
   Get-HardDisk $vm.Vm | Select -first 1 | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB ([math]::round(($vm.Disks[0].Capacity + $space - $vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace) / $gb))
}
```

Take care when running, particularly if you have machines with multiple hard disks.

Assuming Windows VMs, you don't need to stop the VM.  You can resize the filesystem remotely using `Invoke-Command` or `Invoke-VMScript`.

Comment: Thank you for the prospective solution. I have tested it and it works, however, I'm not sure how it works. It seems that it doesn't set the disk space to just flat GB but rather set it to 75.53621673583984. I don't quite understand the 1024 * 1024 * 1024, and how this sets the disk size to 75 GB. Can you please explain this solution? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer to give a more detailed explanation and address the weird disk sizes issue.

Comment: this makes more sense in understanding it. I pretty much gathered this but having you explain clears up what I didn't understand. I checked the machine that I am testing this on and it is set at 70GB and it has 11GB free space, so for this script to run correctly, it would expand the drive to 89 total capacity. However, that is not the case. The first image shows the drive size and the second image shows a permission prompt to increase drive capacity to 75 (not 89 as it should), the last image shows the error I'm getting. Setting it smaller than actual size. Links to images below

Comment: https://ibb.co/VpYFc8q   
https://ibb.co/0ZvD2dg    
https://ibb.co/PZY7Myn

Comment: Perhaps you could post your current script somewhere?

Comment: You can see the current code here. https://codeshare.io/5onxJM

Comment: The code in my answer (lines 41-46 of your code) uses `$csvobject` as the input machine name.  Where you have it in your script `$csvobject` isn't initialised and you're just picking up some old value.  You need to move it down into the loop at line 48 probably at about line 54.

Comment: So I add your portion of the script to just underneath the "foreach" at lines 43-47. The script runs but completes without doing anything. I ran the debugger and while stepping into the code, it jumps over your script and completes. Here's the new code share. I'm not sure what I'm missing. https://codeshare.io/5Prw8d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228911/discussion-between-webby68-and-mark-elvers).

Comment: I tried chat but you don't seem to be there.  I've not used chat before.  Anyway, looks to be as if your loop may be empty.  Does you CSV file `"C:\Temp\ExpandHDskList.csv"` hold data.  Try adding `Write-Host $csvObject.vmname` into the loop to see which machines are consider.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell 5 or newer you can replace

```
    $gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
```

with

```
    1GB
```

And replace

```
    $space = 30 * $gb
```

with

```
    30GB
```

So, the entire script would look like this

```
    $vm = Get-VMGuest $csvobject.vmname
    if ($vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace -lt 30GB) {
    Get-HardDisk $vm.Vm | Select -first 1 | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB ([math]::round(($vm.Disks[0].Capacity + 30GB - $vm.Disks[0].FreeSpace) / 1GB))}
```